# Can I use Akka.Cluster.Sharding-1.3.13-beta for for production?

Tags: akka.net

I am using akka.net v1.3.13 in my application. But it seems Akka.Cluster.Sharding module is still in beta version. Can I use it for production? When I can expect a stable release for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We just released [Akka.NET v1.3.14](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/releases/tag/1.3.14) earlier today and that includes some important Akka.Cluster.Sharding fixes - I'd recommend using that version going forward.

Regarding Akka.Cluster.Sharding's fitness for production use - the `-beta` tag shouldn't alarm you. That's largely due to Akka.DistributedData, [one of the two coordination modes for Akka.Cluster.Sharding](https://getakka.net/articles/clustering/cluster-sharding.html) (the other being Akka.Persistence) not having a stable serialization format. The default storage mode, Akka.Persistence, is used heavily.

Akka.Cluster.Sharding will be leaving beta in Akka.NET v1.4.0, which is actively being worked on and should be released in the next couple of months.